# Return Output of PyQGIS Processing Plugin as Output for Other Plugin (QGIS 3.14)

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, pyqgis-3

I'm trying to chain together several PyQGIS Processing plugins I've written into one super-plugin. I'm aware that I can do this with the Visual Modeler but a. our team is trying to make a quick user-friendly unified plugin and b. there are a few places where the Visual Modeler wouldn't quite work for our purposes (I'll get into that more below).
The unified plugin should chain together three plugins and output two vector geometry layers.

Here's what the `processAlgorithm(...)` method looks like.

```
    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        # QSCOUT PARAMETERS
        # required parameters
        target_raster = self.parameterAsRasterLayer(parameters, QScoutPinAlgorithm.TARGETING_RASTER_INPUT, context)
        # ...many more parameters...
        panel_size = self.parameterAsInt(parameters, PinDropperAlgorithm.PANEL_SIZE_INPUT, context)

        pin_dropper_alg_params = {
            QScoutPinAlgorithm.TARGETING_RASTER_INPUT: target_raster,
# ...many more parameters...
            PinDropperAlgorithm.PANEL_SIZE_INPUT: panel_size,
            PinDropperAlgorithm.OUTPUT: "memory:"
        }

        pin_drop_out = processing.run("QScout:droppins", pin_dropper_alg_params,
                                      context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        # VALUE GRABBER PARAMS
        vals_raster = self.parameterAsFile(parameters, ValueGrabberAlgorithm.RASTER_INPUT, context)
        val_grab_pins = pin_drop_out[PinDropperAlgorithm.OUTPUT]

        grab_alg_params = {
            ValueGrabberAlgorithm.RASTER_INPUT: vals_raster,
            ValueGrabberAlgorithm.POINTS_INPUT: val_grab_pins,
            ValueGrabberAlgorithm.POINTS_OUTPUT: "memory:"
        }

        grab_alg_out = processing.runAndLoadResults("QScout:valuegrab", grab_alg_params,
                                      context=context, feedback=feedback)

        # GRID AGGREGATOR PARAMS
        grid_w = self.parameterAsDouble(parameters, GridAggregatorAlgorithm.GRID_CELL_W_INPUT, context)
        grid_h = self.parameterAsDouble(parameters, GridAggregatorAlgorithm.GRID_CELL_H_INPUT, context)
        ag_idx = self.parameterAsEnum(parameters, GridAggregatorAlgorithm.AGGREGATION_FUNCTION_INPUT, context)

        points_out = grab_alg_out[ValueGrabberAlgorithm.POINTS_OUTPUT]

        # this is a bit wonky
        fields_to_use = map(lambda f: f.strip(), fields_to_use.split(","))
        ag_fields = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers()[points_out].fields()
        regexes = "|".join(map(lambda r: "(%s)" % r, [ROW_REGEX, COL_REGEX, VINE_REGEX, PANEL_REGEX]))
        ag_fields = filter(lambda f: (not fields_to_use.strip or f.name() in fields_to_use) and
                           not re.match(regexes, f.name()),
                           ag_fields)

        grid_ag_alg_params = {
            ValueGrabberAlgorithm.POINTS_INPUT: points_out,
            GridAggregatorAlgorithm.GRID_CELL_W_INPUT: grid_w,
            GridAggregatorAlgorithm.GRID_CELL_H_INPUT: grid_h,
            GridAggregatorAlgorithm.AGGREGATION_FUNCTION_INPUT: ag_idx,
            GridAggregatorAlgorithm.FIELDS_TO_USE_INPUT: ag_fields,
            GridAggregatorAlgorithm.GRID_OUTPUT: "memory:"
        }

        grid_alg_out = processing.runAndLoadResults("QScout:gridaggregator", grid_ag_alg_params,
                                      context=context, feedback=feedback)

        grid_out = grid_alg_out[GridAggregatorAlgorithm.GRID_OUTPUT]

        return {self.DROP_AND_GRAB_POINTS_OUT: points_out, self.DROP_AND_GRAB_GRID_OUT: grid_out}
```

(the part with `fields_to_use` is one reason I can't use the Graphical Modeler for this)

The outputs for `QScout:valuegrab` and `QScout:gridaggregator` are a vector layers of points and polygons respectively.

The problem I'm having now is that when I run the plugin, it doesn't load the output layers properly. It doesn't give any errors, and when I run `QgsProject.instance().mapLayers()` in the console it shows that the layers are written to memory, but I don't see them in the layer browser. I'm also concerned that the program is keeping the intermediate steps (such as the output for `QScout:droppins`, in memory.

I've looked at [this page](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html) in the manual and a bunch of other questions on this site but none of them have helped.

How do I make the plugin load (or save to files, if the user specifies) the outputs from `QScout:valuegrab` and `QScout:gridaggregator` envoked from within the plugin? I suspect I'm doing quite a few things wrong here.